# Realloc gives error: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, realloc

I have this school assignment where we are given some code to modify. The part im having trouble with is to truncate a dynamically allocated string. We are writing a function where we take in a pointer to the string and the new length of the string (as an int).

```
void dstring_truncate(DString* destination, unsigned int truncatedLength)
{

    assert(destination != NULL);
    assert(*destination != NULL);
    assert(truncatedLength > 0);

    DString temp = (DString)malloc(strlen(*destination) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp, *destination);
    printf("\n%s test dstring truncate\n", temp);
    temp[truncatedLength] = '\0';
    temp = (DString)realloc(temp, truncatedLength + 1);

    *destination[truncatedLength] = '\0';
    *destination = (DString)realloc(*destination, truncatedLength + 1);
    printf("%s test dstring truncate after realloc\n", *destination);
    
}
```

The call to the function looks like this`dstring_truncate(&str1, 10);`
DString is the ADT we are working with `typedef char* DString;`

also the first function in the program initializes the string `DString dstring_initialize(const char* str);`

I assume its me not understanding pointers because the "Temp" in the code above works like intended but the "*destination" does not.

Ive tried using "destination", "*destination", "**destination" and i've rewatched the material given and some youtube/documentation online but i just cant get my head around this.

also this is how i wrote the initialize code maybe there is something wrong here?

```
DString dstring_initialize(const char* str)
{
    assert(str != NULL);
    DString arr = (DString)malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation Failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(arr, str);
    if (strcmp(str, arr) == 0) 
    {
        return arr; // Ersatt denna rad. Den ar just nu med for att programmet ska kompilera
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides that, why duplicate the full string first, then reallocate? Why not allocate the truncated length (plus one for the null-terminator) and then only copy the truncated length?

Comment: Other notes of importance: In C you [should not cast the result of `malloc` or `realloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), or any other function returning `void *`. Also don't reassign back to the pointer you pass to `realloc`. If `realloc` fails it will return a null pointer, but leave the old memory alone. If you reassign back to the same pointer, you loose the original memory. And I don't see your code doing any error checking, or validation that `truncatedLength <= strlen(*destination)` (if they're equal you don't need to do anything).

Comment: Also please try to avoid type-aliases of pointers. It's a bad habit that more often than not lead to problems, and code that is harder to read and maintain.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `strcmp` call in `dstring_initialize`? Since this immediately follows a call to `strcpy` with the same parameters (albeit in the reverse order), the `strcmp` will always return 0. Also, if for some reason it did not return 0, there is no `return` statement to handle that case.

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). (Answer: generally No)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the varable `temp` as is within the function does not make sense because at least it produces a memory leak. I think you included the code with the variable `temp` temporary only for the purpose of testing.

Nevertheless this part of the code contains a bug in this statement

```
 DString temp = (DString)malloc(strlen(*destination) * sizeof(char));
```

You did not reserve memory for the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the created string. Thus this statement

```
strcpy(temp, *destination);
```

overwrites memory beyond the allocated dynamically extent of memory that already results in undefined behavior.

This statement

```
temp[truncatedLength] = '\0';
```

is logically also incorrect because you are not checking that the value of `truncatedLength` is indeed not greater than the length of the source string. Before reallocting a string you need to check that the value of `truncatedLength` is less than the currect length of the source string.

By the way the variable (the function parameter) `truncatedLength` should have  type `size_t` instead of `unsigned int`. `size_t` is the return type  of the function `strlen` and the type of parameters that specify sizes in standard memory allocation functions.

In this statement

```
*destination[truncatedLength] = '\0';
```

there is used invalid order of operators. Instead you need to write

```
( *destination )[truncatedLength] = '\0';
```

And again you need at first to check that `truncatedLength` is not greater than the length of the source string.

The function `realloc` can return a null pointer. In this case you will have a memory leak because the value of the pointer `*destination` will be overwritten in this statement

```
*destination = (DString)realloc(*destination, truncatedLength + 1);
```

You need to use an intermediate variable to which the returned value of the function `realloc` will be assigned.

And you should report to the caller of the function whether realloction was successful. So it is better to declare the return type of the function as `int` instead of `void`.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the functions can be updated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef char *DString;

DString dstring_initialize( const char *str )
{
    assert( str != NULL );

    DString arr = malloc( strlen( str ) + 1 );

    if ( arr == NULL)
    {
        puts( "Memory allocation Failed" );
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy( arr, str );
    }

    return arr;
}

int dstring_truncate( DString *destination, size_t truncatedLength )
{

    assert( destination != NULL );
    assert( *destination != NULL );
    assert( truncatedLength > 0 );

    size_t n = strlen( *destination );

    int success = truncatedLength < n;

    if ( success )
    {
        DString temp = realloc( *destination, truncatedLength + 1 );

        success = temp != NULL;

        if (success)
        {
            *destination = temp;
            ( *destination )[truncatedLength] = '\0';
        }
    }

    return success;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "Hello Wordl!";

    DString ds = dstring_initialize( s );

    if ( ds != NULL )
    {
        int success = dstring_truncate( &ds, strchr( ds, ' ' ) - ds );

        if (success)
        {
            printf( "Now after truncation the string is \"%s\"\n", ds );
        }

        free( ds );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
Now after truncation the string is "Hello"
```

Actually the function `dstring_initialize` should not issue any message. It is the caller of the function based on the return value of the called function will decide whether to issue a message or not. So the function should look the followng wat

```
DString dstring_initialize( const char *str )
{
    assert( str != NULL );

    DString arr = malloc( strlen( str ) + 1 );

    if ( arr != NULL)
    {
        strcpy( arr, str );
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this solved it perfectly and thank you for explaining all the steps so i could understand. A lot of code (the temp you mention for example) is for testing purpose as you mention so its a mess :P

Answer (score 0):

That error is typical when you have gone out of bounds of your previously allocated memory.

Like when you do

```
strcpy(temp, *destination);
```

without allocating space for the null-terminator.

Remember that `strlen` does *not* count the null-terminator.

Quick fix:

```
DString temp = malloc(strlen(*destination) + 1);
```

---

Adding some parts mentioned in my comments, I would recommend a function like this instead:

```
DString dstring_truncate(DString* destination, size_t truncated_length)
{
    if (destination == NULL || *destination == NULL)
    {
        // No source/destination
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t original_length = strlen(*destination);

    if (truncated_length == original_length)
    {
        // No operation
    }
    else if (truncated_length > original_length)
    {
        // Try to make it longer? That's not truncation. No operation
    }
    else
    {
        // Truncate by reallocation
        // Note that this assumes the original buffer was allocated dynamically as well
        DString temp = realloc(*destination, truncated_length + 1);
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            // Allocation failed, keep the old buffer but return as an error
            return NULL;
        }

        // Set the null-terminator
        temp[truncated_length] = '\0';

        // And finally reassign the destination
        *destination = temp;
    }

    // Return the (possibly new) string
    return *destination;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an operator precedence error in this line:

```
    *destination[truncatedLength] = '\0';
```

It should be:

```
    (*destination)[truncatedLength] = '\0';
```

**Explanation:** postfix operators such as the `[` `]` array subscripting operator bind tighter than unary operators such as the unary `*` (indirection) operator, so `*destination[truncatedLength] = '\0';` is actually the same as `*(destination[truncatedLength]) = '\0';` or `*(*(destination + truncatedLength)) = '\0';` or `**(destination + truncatedLength) = '\0'`, which is not what you want. That will treat `destination` as pointing to the first element of an array of `DString` and set the `truncatedLength`th element of that array to `'\0'`. The `'\0'` will be treated as a *null pointer constant* so it is setting the `truncatedLength`th element of the array of `DString` to a null pointer. Unfortunately, `destination` is actually pointing to a single `DString`, not the first element of an array of `DString`, resulting in *undefined behavior* when `truncatedLength > 0`. Adding the parentheses around `*destination` means that the unary `*` operator is applied to `destination` instead of being applied to `destination[truncatedLength]`. `(*destination)[truncatedLength = '\0';` is equivalent to `*((*destination) + truncatedLength) = '\0';` or `*(*destination + truncatedLength) = '\0';`, which is what you want. (Compare `**(destination + truncatedLength)` to `*(*destination + truncatedLength)`.)

The function assumes that `truncatedLength <= strlen(*destination)`. If you want to assert that condition is true during debugging, you could add an `assert` call:

```
    assert(truncatedLength <= strlen(*destination));
```

(Note that `assert` calls will have no effect if the `NDEBUG` macro is defined.)

Alternatively, the function could be written to do nothing when `truncatedLength >= strlen(*destination)`:

```
    if (truncatedLength >= strlen(*destination))
    {
        return;
    }
    (*destination)[truncatedLength] = '\0';
```

It seems reasonable to allow truncation of the string to zero-length, but the existing `assert(truncatedLength > 0);` does not allow that.

It is possible that the call to `realloc()` could return `NULL`. It is unlikely to happen when shrinking the size of the allocated block, but is technically possible.  In that case, the original block remains valid, and since it is large enough, it can be left alone.  The following code only replaces `*destination` if the `realloc()` call was successful:

```
    DString tempdest = realloc(*destination, truncatedLength + 1);
    if (tempdest != NULL)
    {
        *destination = tempdest;
    }
```

Note that there is no need to cast the `void *` value returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` because the `=` will automatically convert the `void *` value on the right hand side to the type of the pointer object on the left hand side of the `=`.

There is some inconsistency in the use of `sizeof(char)` as a scaling factor, so the above code could be changed to:

```
    DString tempdest = realloc(*destination, (truncatedLength + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (tempdest != NULL)
    {
        *destination = tempdest;
    }
```

Note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so all those `* sizeof(char)` factors can be removed.  (For a version that works on `wchar_t`, the `* sizeof(wchar_t)` factors would need to be kept.)

There is also a problem in the experiments with the `temp` variable. In these lines:

```
    DString temp = (DString)malloc(strlen(*destination) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp, *destination);
```

The first line does not allocate enough space for the null terminator character, so the second line writes past the end of the allocated memory. The memory pointed to by `temp` is never freed, so this is also a memory leak bug, but I understand it is just an experiment.

Putting all that altogether and removing the `temp` experiment, we could end up with something like this:

```
void dstring_truncate(DString* destination, unsigned int truncatedLength)
{
    assert(destination != NULL);
    assert(*destination != NULL);

    if (truncatedLength >= strlen(*destination))
    {
         return;
    }
    DString tempdest = realloc(*destination, truncatedLength + 1);
    if (tempdest != NULL)
    {
        *destination = tempdest;
    }
    (*destination)[truncatedLength] = '\0';
}
```

In `dstring_initialize()`, not all paths through the function return a value, but since the `if` condition at the end of the function will always be true, the code following the `if` statement will never be reached anyway. There is no need for the final `if` statement with its call to `strcmp`. Just return `arr` after the call to `strcpy()`:

```
DString dstring_initialize(const char* str)
{
    assert(str != NULL);
    DString arr = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation Failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(arr, str);
    return arr;
}
```